# Cómo contar registros y agruparlos por tipo?

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta SQL en cual cuenta los resultados y los agrupa por tipo de habitacion
la relacion que manejo es Rooms tiene un rooms_types

```
return DB::table('rooms')
        ->leftJoin('room_types', 'room_types.id', '=', 'rooms.room_type_id')
        ->select('room_types.room_type_name as name',DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))
        ->where('rooms.status', '=', 'Activo')
        ->groupBy('room_types.room_type_name')
        ->get();
```

la consulta esta bien pero no me obtiene si no existe el tipo de habitacion registrado a una habitacion manejo 3 tipos de habitaciones: simple, doble, Matrimonial de momento son 3 pero la consulta solo me cuenta los que estan asociados a una habitacion(rooms) Ejemplo:

```
name       | total
-------------------
simple     | 2
doble      | 1
```

y no me muestra el tipo de habitacion matrimonial por que aun esta registrado en la tabla rooms,
de donde saco el conteo, el resultado que deseo obtener que muestre todos los tipos de habitaciones mostrando los totales de cada tipo ejemplo

```
name        | total
-------------------
simple      | 2
doble       | 1
matrimonial | 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes invertir el orden de las tablas para obtener todas los `room_types`. De este modo, no depende de si hay o no registros en `rooms`.

```
return DB::table('room_types')
    ->leftJoin('rooms', 'room_types.id', '=', 'rooms.room_type_id')
    ->select('room_types.room_type_name as name',DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))
    ->where('rooms.status', '=', 'Activo')
    ->groupBy('room_types.room_type_name')
    ->get();
```

Ademas, para contar los registros, puedes usar cualquier campo no nulo de la tabla `rooms`, por ejemplo `COUNT(rooms.room_type_id)`

Finalmente, para que puestre todos los registros, no puedes agregar una condicion sobre la tabla `rooms` de esa manera, tampoco mostrara entradas que no esten en `rooms`.

Comment: No termino de entender la solución que propones, considerando que el OP usa leftJoin ¿podrías ampliar?

Comment: @BetaM el OP dice "la consulta solo me cuenta los que estan asociados a una habitacion" por lo que la tabla pivote no contiene todos los tipos. Usar como pivote `room_types` permitirá siempre incluir todos los tipos y el `count()` sera cero para los que no tengan registro en `rooms`

Comment: Ahhh muy bien, ya comprendí mejor tu solución, gracias +1

Answer (score 0):

logre solucionar de la siguiente manera

```
return DB::table('room_types')
        ->select('room_types.room_type_name as name', DB::raw('COUNT(rooms.room_type_id) as total'))
        ->leftJoin('rooms', 'rooms.room_type_id', '=', 'room_types.id')
        ->groupBy('room_types.room_type_name')
        ->get();
```

que gracias a la aclaracion de F.Igor de envertir la consulta y que tambien nesecitaba contar por id que relaciona a las dos tablas